# How to bin a variable that has many unique values to buckets in Pandas based on their occurrence frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                  'cat':['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

I would like to create a new column to the existing dataframe, called `t_cat` where `t_cat` is going to be `cat` but `binned` into 2 categories, based on `nunique()` (based on their occurrence frequency), this means that the `a` `cat` will be one category and then `b` and `c` `cat` will be binned together.

To put it in other words:  I would like to dynamically create the bins based on the occurrence frequency of the unique values of the `cat` column

I thought of using `pd.qcut()`: `pd.qcut(df.groupby('cat')['id'].nunique(),q=2,  duplicates='drop')` but it doesnt work as expected.

My output ideally would look like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                  'cat':['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
                       't_cat':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]})
```

Any ideas how to do this neatly ?

Comment: Why are they binned together, b and c?

Comment: based on their occurrence frequency

Comment: What would happen if the frequency of b is 4?

Comment: then again you have the same groups because the `frequency of a` is 6, and `frequency of b` + `frequency of c` = 7. So basically get the quantiles and then group them accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df['t_cat'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('cat')['id'].transform('nunique'), 2, labels=[2, 1])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id cat t_cat
0    1   a     1
1    2   a     1
2    3   a     1
3    4   a     1
4    5   a     1
5    6   a     1
6    7   b     2
7    8   b     2
8    9   b     2
9   10   c     2
10  11   c     2
11  12   c     2
```

Comment: how does the `labels` work ? the first value goes to the highest interval ?

Comment: The first label goes to the lowest interval, the second one to the highest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from numpy for this case.  Here, the value `1` is assigned to the entry with the highest number of unique values and `2` is assigned to everything else.

```
top_n = 1
>>> df.assign(
        t_cat=np.where(
            df['cat'].isin(df['cat'].value_counts().head(top_n).index), 1, 2))
    id cat  t_cat
0    1   a      1
1    2   a      1
2    3   a      1
3    4   a      1
4    5   a      1
5    6   a      1
6    7   b      2
7    8   b      2
8    9   b      2
9   10   c      2
10  11   c      2
11  12   c      2
```

Comment: maybe my question wasnt clear enough. I would like to dynamically create the bins based on the occurrence frequency of the unique values of the `cat` column

Comment: Yes, I was just going to comment on ways to do that, but your question is not clear on what you'd like.